# How to search only documents from library

Tags: search-results, sharepoint-search

I am trying below search query to search document from specific library but now this library have nested folders where documents are kept , how to modify my query so it only search for documents (pdf,doc,xls) not show folders

query which i am using now

```
path:"https://Sharepoint.com/sites/Test1/Lib1*" 
path:"https://Sharepoint.com/sites/Test2/Lib2*"
path:"https://Sharepoint.com/sites/Test3/LIb3*" 
path:"https://Sharepoint.com/sites/Test4/Lib4*"
```

Comment: try this "https://Sharepoint.com/sites/Test1/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for documents only by adding this query part:

```
IsDocument:"True"
```

If you want to narrow it down to specific extensions, you can use this:

```
(FileExtension:doc OR FileExtension:docx OR FileExtension:xls OR FileExtension:xlsx OR FileExtension:ppt OR FileExtension:pptx OR FileExtension:pdf) (IsDocument:"True" OR contentclass:"STS_ListItem")
```

(extracted from the *Documents* result source)